# Casting from Object[] to String[] gives a ClassCastException

Tags: java, swing, java-7, jogl

The `getStrings()` method is giving me a `ClassCastException`. Can anyone tell me how I should get the model? Thanks!

```
public class HW3model extends DefaultListModel<String>
{           
    public HW3model()
    {
        super();
    }

    public void addString(String string)
    {
        addElement(string);
    }

    /**
     * Get the array of strings in the model.
     * @return
     */
    public String[] getStrings()
    {
         return (String[])this.toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `toArray` method?

Comment: It's a method of DefaultListModel that I'm calling. I should not have used "this"

Comment: He's using the method of the super class. But it doesn't return an array of String but rather an array of Object. So that's your problem. Treat it for what it is, an array of object.

Comment: Is there any way to convert it cast it to a String array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned by `toArray` is an `Object` array.

That is, they've be declared as `Object[]`, not `String[]`, then returned back via a `Object[]`.

This means you could never case it to `String` array, it's simply invalid.

You're going to have to copy the values yourself...for example

```
public String[] getStrings()
    Object[] oValues= toArray();
    String[] sValues = new String[oValues.length];
    for (int index = 0; index < oValues.length; index++) {
        sValues[index] = oValues[index].toString();
    }
    return sValues;
}
```

Comment: You have to admire the courage of down voters who are unable to provide a comment as to why they felt it necessary to apply a downvote. It does nothing to help the poster or future posters to improve this or future questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast one array into the type of another, so you'd have to ensure that you create your own array:

```
public String[] getStrings() {
    String[] result = new String[getSize()];
    copyInto(result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this and see if that would work

```
String[] stringArrayX = Arrays.copyOf(objectArrayX, objectArrayX.length, String[].class);
```